# Deployment for staging and production

Tags: deployment

I need to make the deployment easy between my staging and production servers.

How can I do this? I need to deploy all the changes, so if I pull from Github and run the script, the changes are applied!

Has anyone written any script or module for this?

I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 9):

You should look into [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush), [drush deploy](http://drupal.org/project/drush_deploy) and especially [features](http://drupal.org/project/features).  Not all Drupal configuration options are supported by features, and you will need to do some work to create a deployment process that works for you.  There is no single script that will do everything correctly for you.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this twice. :-) I'll add that with drush you can create a makefile for your site. http://drupal.org/project/drush_make

Comment: Thanks.  n.b. drush_make is included in Drush core version 7.x-5.x; if you are still using Drush 4, it would be a good idea to upgrade.  Also, you can generate a Drush Makefile from an existing Drupal site via drush generate-make. There is a work-in-progress command to build an install profile from an existing Drupal site at http://drupal.org/node/1368242.

Answer (score 4):

There is [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/)

> Advanced Deployment Tools Deploy your repositories to (S)FTP, SSH and
>   Amazon S3 in one click.

And there is [GitHub's post-receive hooks](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks).

GitHub will POST to a supplied URL when someone pushes to the repo. Just write a short PHP script to run on your linode VPS and pull from GitHub when it receives said POST.

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/)

> Fabric is a Python library and command-line tool for streamlining the
>   use of SSH for application deployment or systems administration tasks.
>
> It provides a basic suite of operations for executing local or remote
>   shell commands (normally or via sudo) and uploading/downloading files,
>   as well as auxiliary functionality such as prompting the running user
>   for input, or aborting execution.

You may also be interested in [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) for command line access to Drupal.

e.g, some relevant drush commands:

```
archive-dump    Backup your code, files, and database into a single file.                                                                                                                                                                       
archive-restore Expand a site archive into a Drupal web site. 
core-rsync (rsync)    Rsync the Drupal tree to/from another server using ssh.
```

or both :)

Comment: can i do with a script, to perform all the changes

Comment: Yes, you could script the entire thing so it's automatic.

Answer (score 3):

Although the question is a year before I would suggest using these 3 tools.

[Git](http://git-scm.com/) + [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) + [Drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush).

It just works for such kind of tasks.

Here are some **Capistrano gems/files** related to Drupal to help you automate Drupal development:

- http://rubygems.org/gems/capistrano-drupal
- http://rubygems.org/gems/capdrupal
- https://github.com/chadfennell/dapistrano

And here are some useful resources so you don't have to search all over the web:

- [Jochen Verdeyen - DEPLOYING DRUPAL WITH CAPISTRANO (video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nDrxmmqC64g)
- [Simple and powerful site deployment with capistrano - Kim Pepper (video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ulK-lhv8eI0)
- [DrupalCon Munich 2012: Deploy with Capistrano (video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvkiWfjmKQ4)
- [Deploying Drupal With Git and Capistrano (blog)](http://www.58bits.com/blog/2013/03/23/deploying-drupal-with-capistrano)

Answer (score 2):

These are my finding. Drush provides the sync, using mysql dump and restore as complete, not the changes made after some interval.

Many things can be tracked with
 - Configuration Module
 - Features
 - Extra Features

Please see the presentation for further.
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6Sp-HBmxgGMMnhhQXVrR1hDUVU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. May you expend your answer with a summary of what reported in the linked page. On Stack Exchange, answers merely containing a link are not considered answers.