# how to export custom installed module(s) configurations?

Tags: 7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deployment for staging and production](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54518/deployment-for-staging-and-production)

how can i export the change in configuration of a custom install module, configuration module is exporting configurations of these, components Content type,Field,Image style,Variable,Permission, Vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

These are my finding. Drush provides the sync, using mysql dump and restore as complete, not the changes made after some interval.
Many things can be tracked with

- Configuration Module
- Features
- Extra Features

Please see the presentation for futher.
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6Sp-HBmxgGMMnhhQXVrR1hDUVU/edit?usp=sharing