# There were errors validating the config synchronization after changes to modules and config

Tags: drush, configuration, deployment

After many hurdles, struggles, and "learning moments", I pushed my site to staging successfully. Unfortunately, I am running into numerous issues when I try to push updates to a deployed site.

I read [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54518/deployment-for-staging-and-production) where the answer was basically that every deployment/update process is going to be different and you have to figure it out yourself. I researched this and came up with a process, but it is broken and results in a failed update, or loss of data added by test users. If I use this process in production I am concerned it will also result in an outage, so I am hoping to iron it out and understand what I'm doing wrong.

## Change Context

In this case, assume I deployed a version of the site to staging. After this, I make local changes to the site, including:

- Deleting a SAML module that is causing issues and replacing it with another module
- Configuration changes including views and custom content type changes
- Styling changes to my custom theme

In the meantime, the staging site is being tested, so users have created content. In other words, I can't simply import my local database, and instead need to update the staging database with any config changes that occurred in my local site. I also `.gitignore` my `settings.php` file and my `files` folder.

Lastly, all of these changes are working locally and dummy content in my local database is behaving as expected. It is only the staging site that is having problems when I try to pull my local changes and update the database.

## Current Process

This is the broken process I have now. The steps marked i) are ones I found when researching the process, but which do not work for me. The steps marked ii) and subsequent steps are the workarounds I attempted to fix the issue, but either seem dubious, or outright fail to it.

1. I make changes mentioned in the above context, and run `drush cex` to export my config.
2. Using git, I merge changes into my main branch.
3. i) I SSH into the staging server and attempt to pull the changes, but this results in an error saying that the pull failed because git would overwrite a large list of files. I don't have the list any more, but they included `composer.json` which I am okay to replace, but also includes numerous other files that were created automatically or are module dependencies.
4. ii) I do a `git reset --hard` and `git pull` again, which works this time, but is slightly concerning because of the destroyed files.
5. i) I run `drush cim` which results in the error:

```
[error]  Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporterException: There were errors validating the config synchronization.

Unable to install the <em class="placeholder">miniorange_saml</em> module since it does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporter->validate() (line 814 of /var/www/websites/cabstg/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/ConfigImporter.php).
```

4. ii) I figured this occurred because locally, I uninstalled the module before removing it from my `composer.json` and modules folder. When I pulled the change, it removed this module without uninstalling it from the staging database. I found answers that suggested to re-add the module and remove it as an admin so that it is removed from the staging database, then to remove it from root. I ran `composer require 'drupal/miniorange_saml:^3.0'` in staging, then manually uninstalled it, removed it from composer, and ran `composer update` like I did locally to remove this module. Then, I run `Drush cim` again. Unfortunately, it results in the same error once again.
5. iii) I took the additional step of searching my config directory for "miniOrange" but could not find it, so I do not why `Drush cim` is attempting to "install the miniorange_saml" in the first place. If anything, it should be uninstalling miniorange and any related configuration/data.
6. iiii) I ran `Drush updb` in case this error is caused by an old entry in the database, and rerun `Drush cim` but this does not work.

From here, I am not sure how to proceed further and I am forced to re-deploy the site. This means that I can either deploy a backup **without the changes I made** so I can keep the data added by users in staging, or I can push my change and import my working local database **at the cost of losing content** that the users added.

I feel like I am missing a step or misunderstanding this process. How do I push this change correctly?

## Additional info

I read numerous questions on stack exchange with a similar error, but most of these were caused by blocks and not modules. I attempted the solutions where they seemed applicable, but no solution has worked for me yet.

Comment: In step 5)i, is the module code present when that command runs, or isn't it?

Comment: First deployment should disable the module (removed entry in core.extension.yml and removed module config). Second deployment should remove the module from the filesystem (via compser.json/.lock). As @cilefen says: The module needs to be present to get uninstalled, to get possible uninstall hooks in that module run and clean up a bit. You can't uninstall a module that's not there.

Comment: I am ashamed to say I missed the obvious. Drush cex exports to my files/ directory by default which is in my .gitignore. The config folder contained outdated config from before, which is why it was failing. I used cyberduck to delete the old config folder and upload the new one, and "[success] The configuration was imported successfully."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order of drush commands for automated deployment?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/254407/order-of-drush-commands-for-automated-deployment)

Comment: Hahaha, we've all been there. Glad you sorted it out.